# React: Map data horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have some data that I am mapping into cards. By default they are mapped vertically under each other (see the screenshot below). However, I would like them to be mapped horizontally next to each other. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? (
      <div>
    <Card className="card" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Body>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
        <h2>{number.s[0].l}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="vl"></div>
        <div className="col">
        <h4>{number.s[0].d[0]}</h4>
        {number.s[0].ta} 
        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={()=>this.deleteCard(number.s[0].ta)} icon={faTrashAlt} />
        </div>
        </div>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <p></p>
    </div>
  ) : null
})}
      </div>
    );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to put the Card in

```
X Y Z
```

instead of

```
X
Y
Z
```

then I would recommend putting a container with a display: flex

```
    return (
        <div class="container" style={{display: "flex"}}>
          {this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? (
      <div>
    <Card className="card" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Body>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
        <h2>{number.s[0].l}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="vl"></div>
        <div className="col">
        <h4>{number.s[0].d[0]}</h4>
        {number.s[0].ta} 
        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={()=>this.deleteCard(number.s[0].ta)} icon={faTrashAlt} />
        </div>
        </div>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <p></p>
    </div>
  ) : null
})}
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "flex-direction: row" on outer div (above the map function) or provide more info about "this.state.serials" data...

Example

```
.container{ 
            display: flex; 
            flex-direction: row;
          }
```